# ¿Por qué me da error al acceder a mi mssql server a través una aplicación en java?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, netbeans

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion en java para acceder a mi mssql server y dentro del ide (NETBEANS) me funciona correctamente, pero cuando le doy a compilar y ejecuto el .jar me funciona correctamente todo hasta en el momento que hace el acceso a la base de datos y me dice que no encuentra el driver:

java.lang.classnotfoundexception com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserverdriver

¿Por qué puede ser esto?

Comment: Claramente tu aplicación no tiene empaquetado el driver. Abre el jar (winzip, 7zip...) y mira si dentro se ve tu driver. Seguro que no. Debes empaquetarlo en la aplicación.

Comment: Debe  de añadirse en algún sitio en concreto dentro del .jar? Efectivamente no estaba añadido, pensaba que con crear el path dentro de netbeans se añadía solo.

Comment: Ningún sitio concreto. Debe estar en el classpath para que puedas accederlo. Lo puedes meter en un directorio lib y listo. Como no se sabe cómo invocas el driver... supongo que con `Class.forName`

Comment: Si, lo invoco con Class.forName: Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            String url = "jdbc:sqlserver....

Comment: Pero sigue saliendome el mismo error....dentro del ide me va perfecto, pero luego fuera falla

Comment: Cuando exportas el jar le debes decir que incluya el jar del driver.

Comment: Eso se haría en el apartado de Build en las propiedades del proyecto? Porque ya tengo marcado que trackee las dependencias de java.

Comment: Lo siento pero no utilizo netbeans, así que no sé cómo se hace ahí. Debe haber alguna opción de *qué* incluir en el jar (ficheros compilados, c´digo duente etc). En algún sitio se debe poder decir, cuales de las librerías del proyecto, hay que añadir al jar.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, seguiré investigando!